# Retrieving values of a Set collection?

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong with the following code!  Im this code I'm attempting to retrieve the contents of a Set collection and post them on a JList!

```
//Populating the SystemDSN List
Set systemDSN = OdbcSystemDSNListUtil.getODBCSystemDSN();

Object[] systemDSNList = systemDSN.toArray();
DefaultListModel systemDSNListNodes = new DefaultListModel();
for (int i = 0; i < systemDSNList.length; i++) {
    systemDSNListNodes.add(i, systemDSNList[i]);
    System.out.println(systemDSNList[i]);
}

jList_SystemDSN.setModel(dataSetListNodes);
```

This is what I get in the print out,

```
Default Group
ODBC Data Sources
ODBC File DSN
geeshe
```

And even though the "Default Group" is an entity of some other list, I only get that as the only item shown on the intended JList!

Comment: You're not using `dataSetListNodes` anywhere in the code before the last line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this:

```
jList_SystemDSN.setModel(dataSetListNodes);
```

to be this:

```
jList_SystemDSN.setModel(systemDSNListNodes);
```

? If so, that's the answer. If not, you should edit the question so it makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks heaps for seeing this error!  I think I need to get some rest before I loose my senses!